# Make @JsonTypeInfo property optional

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using `@JsonTypeInfo` to instruct Jackson to look in the `@class` property for concrete type information.  However, sometimes I don't want to have to specify `@class`, particularly when the subtype can be inferred given the context.  **What's the best way to do that?**

Here's an example of the JSON:

```
{ 
    "owner": {"name":"Dave"},
    "residents":[
        {"@class":"jacksonquestion.Dog","breed":"Greyhound"},
        {"@class":"jacksonquestion.Human","name":"Cheryl"},
        {"@class":"jacksonquestion.Human","name":"Timothy"}
    ]
}
```

and I'm trying to deserialize them into these classes (all in `jacksonquestion.*`):

```
public class Household {
    private Human owner;
    private List<Animal> residents;

    public Human getOwner() { return owner; }
    public void setOwner(Human owner) { this.owner = owner; }
    public List<Animal> getResidents() { return residents; }
    public void setResidents(List<Animal> residents) { this.residents = residents; }
}

public class Animal {}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    private String breed;
    public String getBreed() { return breed; }
    public void setBreed(String breed) { this.breed = breed; }
}

public class Human extends Animal {
    private String name;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
}
```

using this config:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
private static class AnimalMixin {
}

//...

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Animal.class, AnimalMixin.class);
Household household = objectMapper.readValue(json, Household.class);
System.out.println(household);
```

As you can see, the owner is declared as a Human, not an Animal, so I want to be able to omit `@class` and have Jackson infer the type as it normally would.

When I run this though, I get

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), 
   expected FIELD_NAME: missing property '@class' that is to contain type id  (for class jacksonquestion.Human)
```

Since "owner" doesn't specify `@class`.

Any ideas?  One initial thought I had was to use `@JsonTypeInfo` on the property rather than the type.  <strike>However, this cannot be leveraged to annotate the element type of a list.</strike>  (Incorrect, see answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should not actually do this -- it seems like a micro-optimization for special cases, complicating life -- but if you really think you do want to, you can try adding `@JsonTypeInfo` override on Human. Annotations are inheritable in Jackson, and you can override definitions. In this case which one gets used then depends on declared type: so anything declared as `Human` would see annotation on `Human`; and anything declared as `Animal` only one in `Animal.

One tricky case is the root value (value you directly serialize): since there is no declared type, it will use the runtime type. And this will probably not work the way you want.

Another possibility is sub-classing `AnnotationIntrospector`: you can change the handling of `@JsonTypeInfo` there as well; just see what `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` does, override behavior as applicable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Overriding the type on Human is one avenue I explored, however (if I'm remembering correctly) I ran into the problem that I think you describe in your second paragraph...when I tried to then include a `Human` in a `List<Animal>` it complained.  I'm going to post an answer with how I got around the issue, but the AnnotationIntrospector looks like an worthy path if I wanted to continue down the "optional annotation" path.

Answer (score 3):

So it turns out that I had misunderstood the [Javadoc for `@JsonTypeInfo`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonTypeInfo.html).  When I said in my question

> One initial thought I had was to use @JsonTypeInfo on the property rather than the type. However, this cannot be leveraged to annotate the element type of a list.

I was basing that on this quote from the Javadoc:

> When used for properties (fields, methods), this annotation applies to values: so when applied to structure types (like Collection, Map, arrays), will apply to contained values, not the container; for non-structured types there is no difference. (...) There is no per-property way to force type information to be included for type of container (structured type); for container types one has to use annotation for type declaration.

I somehow misread that to mean the opposite; that the type info would apply to the container and not the elements.  Obviously that was wrong.  So I was able to fix this by using the following:

```
public class Household {
   //...

   @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@class")
   public void setResidents(List<Animal> residents) { 
      this.residents = residents; 
   }
}
```

Now `@class` is only required for Animals that are specified in the `residents` property.

Comment: FWIW, this way (of applying to elements) was heavily influenced by JAXB, which has this behavior.

Comment: True, the parts of the Javadoc that I omitted above include *"This is identical to how JAXB handles type information annotations; and is chosen since it is the dominant use case."*  And I agree that it is the dominant use case.